# C++ loop not working as expected

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to plot where the x and y variables are in an array, and when the x or y value is greater than its respective dimension in the array, they should change direction. However, when I run the program the Y value keeps going up. I am new to C++ so any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#define PI 3.14159265
#include <iostream>
#include <tgmath.h>

int timeRun = 0;
int rect[500][1000] = {0};
int theta = 50;
int x = 0;
float y = 0;
float previousY = 0;
int yGo;
int dir = 0;//0 = right; 1 = left;
int main()
{
    for(int a = 30; a<=89; a=a+1){
        memset(rect,0,sizeof(rect));
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        theta = a;
        std::cout << theta;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int t = 0; t<1000;t=t+1){
            y = previousY + tan(theta * PI/180);
            previousY = y;
            yGo = floor(y);
            rect[x][yGo] = 1;
            if(dir==0){
                x++;
            }
            if(dir==1){
                x--;
            }
            if(x>499 && dir==0){
                dir = 1;
            if(theta%360 >= 270 && theta%360 <= 360){
                theta+=(a-180);
            }

        }
        if(x<1 && dir==1){
            dir = 0;
            if(theta%360 >= 0 && theta%360 <= 90){
                theta+=(180-a);
            }
        }
        if(y>998 && dir ==0){
            theta+=(a-180);
        }
        if(y>998 && dir ==1){
            theta+=(180-a);
        }
        if(y<1 && dir ==0){
            theta+=(180-a);
        }
        if(y<1 && dir ==1){
            theta+=(a-180);
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < 500; i++ ){
        for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; j++ ){
            sum+=rect[i][j];
        }
    }
        std::cout << sum;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is there a need for ((theta % 360) <= 360)?  Isn't that the result of the % operator?

Comment: When asking others for help with code you've written, comments explaining the code and proper/consistent indentation are appreciated.

Comment: You may want to think about what happens when `y = previousY + tan(theta * PI/180);` becomes negative. I'm pretty sure `rect[x][-anything]` isn't on your planned agenda. Fyi, as written this will happen on the third iteration of your `t` loop, first iteration of your `a` loop.

Comment: Are all the `if` statements to be in the `for` loop?

Comment: You can eliminate one of the `if` statements by creating an "additive" value that is either +1 or -1 and add it to `x`.  When changing direction, multiply the "additive" value by -1.

Comment: can you explain the code a little bit more.. what its trying to.

Comment: Inside the `t` `for` loop, you never check the variable `x` for out of bounds.  There is nothing  to prevent the `x` index from going negative.

Comment: Before you access the `rect` array, print the indices and the value.  I think this would provide valuable insight into how your program is behaving.  Print out the value of `t` also.

Comment: You should factor out the `if(theta` statement outside of the `for(t` loop.  The value of `theta` doesn't change within the loop.

Comment: The result of `tan(theta * PI/180.0)` should be calculated before the `for(t`) loop and stored into a temporary variable.  It's a constant (invariant) within the `for(t)` loop.  The `for(a)` loop alters `theta`.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand your program.  I simplified the core to:

```
static const float radian_conversion = 3.14159264f / 180.0f;
int     x = 0;
float   y = 0.0f;
int     theta = 30;
int     dir_add = 1;
cout << "t | x | y | theta" << endl;
const float y_increment = tan(theta * radian_conversion);
for (int t = 0; t < 1000; ++t)
{
    y = y + y_increment;
    cout << t << "|" << x << "|" << y << "|" << theta << "\n";
    int y_index = floor(abs(y));
    rect[x][y_index] = 1;
    x = x + dir_add;
    if ((x > 499) || (x < 1))
    {
        dir_add = dir_add * -1;
    }
}
```

I'm also showing how you can make the `x` variable increment and decrement.

The statements that don't change or don't cause a variable to change have been extracted out of the loop.

I recommend you take the output of the above program into a spreadsheet program and have the spreadsheet program plot it.